# How to extract data which is sent from ajax request as a Json Array of objects repetitively in spring-mvc controller?

Tags: java, arrays, json, spring-mvc

I am sending a set of data as Json Array of objects from ajax function to my spring mvc controller method. ie.

```
[{"item":"Cheese Lover","size":"960.00","qty":"1"},{"item":"Garlic Bread","size":"390.00","qty":"1"},{"item":"pudding3","size":"420.00","qty":"2"}]
```

I need to extract these data separately as item, size and qty so that I can feed the fields to sql and send the data to database. But I am got stuck here as I have no idea how to do it properly and this is the controller method which I have used so far.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/add_package")
    public @ResponseBody
    String addPackage(@ModelAttribute("command") Package newPackage,
                      // @RequestBody PackageContent[] content,
                      HttpServletRequest request){
        PackageContent packageContent = new PackageContent();
        String s=request.getParameter("test");

        ObjectMapper objectMapper=new ObjectMapper();
        JSONObject obj= new JSONObject();

        try {
            obj=objectMapper.readValue(s, JSONObject.class);
            obj.get(packageContent.getItem());

            /*for(PackageContent content1 : s){
                //System.out.println(content1.getItem());
                LOGGER.trace("hhh  "+content1.getItem());
            }*/

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("error {}",e);
        }

        return obj.toString();}
```

When I log the result in console,in ajax success function it shows only as `{}`.
I am doing this on form submit button click and is it wrong to do so? If so
when and how can I extract these data repetitively in controller so that send them to the sql code?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Class ListOfItems{
    List<Items> listItems;
    //Getters and Setters

// Use Jackson Here to Convert 
ListOfItems itemList = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, ListOfItems.class);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    class Items{
    private String item;    
    private String qty;    
    private String size;

//Getters and Setters compulsary because Jackson internally uses getters    
//to set the value     
}
```